# proper way of waiting for a go routine to finish

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I wish to know what is the proper way of waiting for a go routine to finish before exiting the program. Reading some other answers it seems that a bool chan will do the trick, as in [Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/ZFnygUtdSY)

```
func do_stuff(done chan bool) {
    fmt.Println("Doing stuff")
    done <- true
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Main")
    done := make(chan bool)
    go do_stuff(done)
    <-done
    //<-done
}
```

I have two questions here:

- why the <- done works at all?
- what happens if I uncomment the last line? I have a deadlock error. Is this because the channel is empty and there is no other function sending values to it?

Comment: `<- done` works because that's just what channels do :) (see https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements for details). You're right about how uncommenting the second line leads to a deadlock. There's nothing sending to `done` and Go recognizes that there's not even anything that *can* if it waits (e.g., nothing waiting on a network call).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why the `<- done` works at all?

- It works because the runtime detects that you're writing something to the channel somewhere else.

what happens if I uncomment the last line?

- The runtime is smart enough to know that there's nothing else being written and it deadlocks.

Bonus, if you're extremely limited on memory, you can use `done := make(chan struct{})` and `done <- struct{}{}`, `struct{}` is guaranteed to use 0 memory.

Comment: Did you miss a negative? "is smart enough" + "deadlocks" — I would think that if it's smart it won't deadlock, instead it gives you an error saying it would. So it seems to me that the either the runtime is NOT smart enough, or it is and it does NOT deadlock. Which is it?

Comment: It's smart enough because it gives you an error telling you that it deadlocked.

Answer (score 12):

Listening to channel `<- done`, is a blocking operation, so your program won't continue until true or false is sent i.e. `done <- true`.

Your question can have a few different answers depending on the circumstance.

For instance, suppose you wanted to parallelize a series of function calls that take a long time.

I would use the `sync` package for this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            longOp()
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    // will wait until wg.Done is called 10 times
    // since we made wg.Add(1) call 10 times
    wg.Wait()
}

func longOp() {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    fmt.Println("long op done")
}
```