# Second channel causing deadlock even if independent

Tags: concurrency, go, goroutine

This is more a follow up question from [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954481/proper-way-of-waiting-for-a-go-routine-to-finish)

I do not understand why adding a second channel (c2 in my case) will cause a deadlock. Channels are independent and I don't see why c2 is supposed to be blocked

[Link to playground](http://play.golang.org/p/jMpu0kgstF)

```
func do_stuff(done chan bool) {
    fmt.Println("Doing stuff")
    done <- true
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Main")
    done := make(chan bool)
    go do_stuff(done)
    <-done
    //Up tp here everything works
    c2 := make(chan int)
    c2 <- 1
    fmt.Println("Exit ",<-c2)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statements

```
c2 := make(chan int)
c2 <- 1
```

will always block. [Link to Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Cq1KPovjaq).

Because the channel `c2` is unbuffered, the send operation cannot proceed until another goroutine has received the value from the channel. There is no goroutine that can receive from the channel, therefore the send blocks forever.

The [channels section in Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels) is a good place to read about unbuffered channels. Also see the sections on channels and send in the [Go Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec).

The program will work as I think you are expecting if you make `c2` a buffered channel:

```
    c2 := make(chan int, 1)
```

With this change, the send can proceed without synchronizing with a receiver.

[Link to Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/atlNItDcai)

Answer (score 4):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Send statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements)
>
> Communication blocks until the send can proceed. A send on an
>   unbuffered channel can proceed if a receiver is ready.

No receiver is ready.

```
package main

func main() {
    c2 := make(chan int)
    c2 <- 1
}
```

Output:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```